# How to find a button with tags?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-button

I have a recyclerviewAdapter with a button and a onclicklistener, I setting tags to the button. ON a diferent file a fragment I tring to find the button base on those tags.

Is this even posible

```
Date date = new Date();
holder.button.setTag(date);
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.e(TAG, "TAGAS" + holder.button.getTag());
    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(position, holder.button.getTag());
    holder.button.setText("Please wait....");
    holder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    holder.button.setClickable(false);
}
});
```

Diferent file fragment.java

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, String tags) {
        Item clickItem = List.get(position);
        Button button = ????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass button instead of some tag in your custom click listener so you won't need to do searching.

Answer (score 0):

The `View` object in `onClick(View v)` is actually the button, so you can pass it on to the `OnItemClickListener` by using `onItemClick(View v, int position, String tags)`.

But it is hard to understand why you would like to access the button from `OnItemClickListener`.